# Bluetooth Module AVRCP and UART

Tags: bluetooth, uart, avrcp

I wonder before buying Bluetooth modules can stream audio and transmit data at the same time ?

I vill use AVRCP profile or A2DP profile for streaming audio. While using this stream modes can modules send or recieve serial data from smartphone or UART ?

Example module : CSR 8635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surly you can. 
However AVRCP can not streaming audio, it is used for control A2DP(which is the right one to stream audio).
The serial data from smartphone, I assume this is the SPP profile, which absolutely can run with AVRCP/A2DP simultaneously.

Comment: I want to connect headset with phone. And battery stat ect will be sending by serial. Can I make phone calls with A2DP profile ? I mean 1 channel input audio 1 channel output and serial same time.

Comment: what did you mean make phone calls with A2DP profile? did you mean the phone call audio + music streaming same time? most phones does not support phone call audio with music audio simultaneously, if it was in call the the music would be paused.

Comment: I fund out I need to use HFP / HSP for making phone calls. I chance my question to " can I send serial data while HFP is active ? "

Comment: absolutely yes, that's the working method of Bluetooth; different profile can work together(sometimes the bandwidth may vary)